# Latin sentences from 1683 epitaph

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

What does this mean?

"Plantarunt vivi divino lumine coelos. Coelos nunc habitant. Ossa favilla fovet."

It's from a 1683 epitaph for two Danish priests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, not surprisingly, Church Latin rather than Classical; *coel-* with the "O" makes that clear (Classical would be *cael-* with an "A").

> *Plantarunt vivi divino lumine coelos.*
>   While alive in the light of God, [these] men cultivated the Heavens.
>
> *Coelos nunc habitant.*
>   They now dwell in the heavens.
>
> *Ossa favilla fovet.*
>   The ashes keep their bones safe.

Comment: Would a more idiomatic translation of the first be "In their life, these men ..." or is that inaccurate? Also, the men were buried, is there some significance to the *ashes*?

Comment: @meide It's entirely possible I'm wrong about some details, since Church Latin really isn't my forte; _favilla_ means "sparks" as well, so if it were Classical I'd take it as a reference to the stars, but I thought the Church always used _favilla_ for "ashes" (as in _dies irae, dies illa / solvet saeclum in favilla_ "on that day of wrath / the world shall crumble to ashes").

Comment: Though, actually, edited.

Comment: *Divino lumine* might represent life's daytime, in the God-given light they cultivated/tilled Heaven. L.2 they are welcomed home. Line3 is curfew *(ignitegium)* when the ash, *favilla,* is heaped round the embers (the bones they have left behind *ossa)* to keep them safe *(foveo* =cherish) until morning, the final resurrection.

Comment: @Hugh Very nice! Updated my answer in that light